# Count loans for each copy of a DVD and then count how many loans per DVD, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making a DVD Club database and I've finished making tables and relationships. Now I'm writing Queries that might be of use. So, for this case, only three tables are relevant: tblLoans, tblCopies and tblDVDs. Here is the diagram:
[image]

So, what I want to do is count the number each DVD has been picked up. So for example, DVD The Godfather has three copies in my DVD club, the first copy was picked up once, the second wasn't picked up and the third copy was picked up twice. I want to show that the DVD The Godfather has been picked up 1+0+2=3 times. Here is the code I've written so far, but I don't know how to fix it to work properly:

```
SELECT tblDVDs.DVD_ID, tblDVDs.Title, x.Number_Of_Pick_Ups
FROM (SELECT tblLoans.Copy_ID, COUNT(tblLoans.Loan_ID) As Number_Of_Pick_Ups FROM tblLoans LEFT JOIN tblCopies ON tblLoans.Copy_ID=tblCopies.Copy_ID GROUP BY tblLoans.Copy_ID)x
INNER JOIN
tblCopies
ON x.Copy_ID=tblCopies.Copy_ID
INNER JOIN
tblDVDs
ON tblCopies.DVD_ID=tblDVDs.DVD_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set where you join the three tables together will have a row for each loan, so you don;t need to do anything complicated, just count the number of rows and group by DVD.

```
select d.dvd_id,
       d.Title, 
       count(*)
from   tblDVDs d
       inner join tblCopies c on d.DVD_ID = c.DVD_ID
       inner join tblLoans l on c.Copy_ID = l.Copy_ID
group by d.dvd_id,
       d.Title
```